# How to use Multiple RichTextEditors in one ctype

Tags: typo3

My Problem is that i am not able to put more then one richTextEditor in one TCA. This is the Code in the TCA:

```
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['verfuegbarkeitsAbfrage'] = array(
    'showitem' => ' --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
                    bodytext;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext_formlabel;;richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css],
                    rte_enabled;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:rte_enabled_formlabel,
                    bodytext;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext_formlabel;;richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css],
                    rte_enabled;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:rte_enabled_formlabel,
                    mod022_NeckarComVerfuegbar,
                    mod022_nichtVerfuegbar,
                    --div--;Additional Classes,
                    --palette--;Margin;fred_marginclasses,
                    --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,
                    --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,
                    --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,
                    --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
                    --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.extended
                    --div--;Gridelements,
                    tx_gridelements_container,
                    tx_gridelements_columns,
                    '
);
```

This is the output when im opening the typo3-Backend:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not use the `bodytext` field twice in the same ctype. The right way is to create a second field which is configured as "textfield"

ext_tables.sql

```
#
# Table structure for table 'tt_content'
#
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    bodytext2 text,
);
```

TCA Field:

```
'bodytext2' => array(
        'label' => 'Text Field 2',
        'config' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['bodytext']['config'],
    ),
```

Then add the Field to your `showitem` array

Enable RTE for `bodytext2`

```
'columnsOverrides' => [
    'bodytext2' => ['defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_css]'],
],
```